# I am getting a issue with the text editor plugin youtube

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor4

When I am trying to add the video using youtube plugin in ckeditor4 the preview is visible but when I am trying to edit the content the preview of the video is not visible in ckeditor there is only iframe preview is there This is coming on edit page preview [This is what I am getting on edit page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFsEH.png)

I am expecting that on edit the preview of the video should also be visible expected [This is what I want on my edit page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmfpa.png)

Comment: "This is what I want on my edit page preview" click this link and you will be able to get what i want actually  " This is what I am getting on edit page preview" on this link you will get what i am actually getting in the edit page in ckeditor content

Comment: actually I am getting the iframe box on edit page in ckeditor but actually I want the preview of the youtube video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a example solution probably what i got from your issue. The issue is that by default ckeditor change the content of youtube plugin.
so you can try using putting these lines (allowedContent: true) . I also attaching the example below
[cdeditor with youtube plugin](https://replit.com/@monu-kumarkuma4/VelvetyLumpyHypercard#index.html)